# WaiterError: Waiter ObjectExists failed: Forbidden

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have a requirement to call a lambda function from another account(B) when a file arrives at bucket oon another account(A). I have provided "s3:*" on the bucket policy of account A and "s3:*" to lambda role on account B for account A's bucket. S3 events gets raised and lambda gets called. However, lambda gets object doesn't exist exception. So, I implemented waiter object to wait until lambda can find the object.

```
waiter = s3_client.get_waiter('object_exists')
waiter.wait(Bucket = bucket_name, Key = key)
```

When I manually, dropping the file, it works perfectly fine. But when AWS drops the file (CUR), lambda gets "Waiter ObjectExists failed: Forbidden" exception.

I looked at all old stackoverflow posts, people are saying that only "s3:ListBucket" is needed for headObject. I tried "s3:ListBucket" and "s3:*" but still getting the same error.

Any help on this regards would be highly appreciated.